# How to restrict construction of an object to a privileged client class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, separation-of-concerns

I'm working on some software where certain string identifiers used in string messages refer to either a production address or a test address. There is a formulaic way to convert a production identifier into a test identifier.

However, there is only one set of hardware–not separate systems for production and test.

Each time we connect to a new recipient, there will be an initial development and testing phase for that recipient, and we would like for the identifiers to be safely converted to test identifiers so no actual production messages accidentally get sent. Now, it does not seem right to me for the message generation class to know about test vs. prod--it should be "stupid" about this because test vs. prod is a business level concern. However, the message generation project contains the `Identifier` class as it is responsible for accepting such Identifiers and serializing them.

How can I keep the definition of an `Identifier` within the message generation project, but ensure that all identifiers actually used therein are converted to their test equivalents when appropriate, without throwing procedural/conditional statements all over the place in the business layer?

In the message generation project, here's some sample code for an `Identifier`.

```
public sealed class Identifier {
   private readonly string _identifier;

   public Identifier(string identifier) {
      _identifier = identifier;
   }

   public IdentifierCode { get { return _identifier; } }

   public bool IsTest { get { return _identifier.BeginsWith("X"); } }

   public Identifier ToTestIdentifier() {
       return new Identifier("X" + _identifier.Substring(1);
   }
}
```

In the business layer, here's a sample of how Identifiers might be constructed and used.

```
...
Message1234 message = new MessageBuilder { // from the generation layer
    Sender = new Identifier(messageDetails.senderIdentifierCode),
    Recipient = new Identifier(messageDetails.recipientIdentifierCode),
    MessageDate = DateTime.Parse(messageDetails.date)
}.Build<Message1234>;
```

What kind of design pattern can I use that will make sure that, according to some recipient-sensitive procedural logic (hitting a database or a settings file that is not committed in code or is at the very least, committed in only ONE place), the `Identifier` properties created above will always have `ToTestIdentifier` run on them when the particular recipient is in test mode?

For example, if the `recipientIdentifierCode` is `AARDVARK` (as that recipient is known to be in test state), all Identifiers used in message generation become test identifiers, but if the `recipientIdentifierCode` is `GORILLA` (as that recipient is known to be in production state), all identifiers are left as-is, whether they are production or test?

To give more clarity, I'm trying to avoid this:

```
Identifier sender = new Identifier(messageDetails.senderIdentifierCode);
Identifier recipient = new Identifier(messageDetails.recipientIdentifierCode);

Message1234 message = new MessageBuilder {
   Sender = IsInTestMode(messageDetails.recipientIdentifierCode)
      ? sender.ToTestIdentifier()
      : sender,
   Recipient = IsInTestMode(messageDetails.recipientIdentifierCode)
      ? recipient.ToTestIdentifier()
      : recipient,
   MessageDate = DateTime.Parse(messageDetails.date)
}.Build<Message1234>;
```

This is fragile because it depends on the developer remembering, every single place an `Identifier` is used, to make it contextually test or not according to the proper rules (rules which could change). It also clutters the code–mixing into the algorithm for building messages the unrelated concern about the test/prod state of business entities. I'd like to dependency inject, or decorate, or provide a visitor, or *something* that can enable me to do it more like this, somewhere in the call chain, just *once* per message request:

```
// Hit the database or do some procedural logic to figure out if test mode is required.
bool shouldBeTestMode = GetTestModeFor(messageDetails.recipientIdentifierCode);

// activate some layer or create some object that wraps/translates/informs
// the rest of the system
MessageGenerationContext = new MessageGenerationContext(shouldBeTestMode);
GoBuildMessages(MessageGenerationContext);

// Now the magic happens somehow so that `new Identifier()` will always return a 
// test identifier without any more code going through conditional contortions
// to make sure the proper kind of identifiers are used.
```

Oh, and to tie in my question title, I would like to make it hard or impossible for random code in the business layer to create an `Identifier` without the special logic being performed that determines whether it needs to be a test one or not, and converting it. Only a specific privileged place in the consumer of the message layer should be able to get to the `Identifier` constructor. All other `new Identifier()` code (or other means of creating identifiers) should be properly buffered so it can't build any test-context-insensitive Identifiers.

Comment: Why not use an app.config configuration file with a setting in there for production or test? Then in the `Identifier` class you can check this flag and if its set, return test identifiers instead of production ones.

Comment: The `Identifier` class is part of the message generation project, which should not know about this setting, or at least should not know how to look up in a database which recipients need to be test or prod. Are you suggesting that I make an IdentifierGenerator class which takes a test/prod bool parameter, and then where current code does `new Identifier()` I instead do `IdentifierGenerator.Generate()` thereafter? One global setting is not sufficient.

Comment: Thats one way to do it, but what is the problem with checking a configuration flag in the `Identifier` class? There are no database operations here, the app.config file is always accessible through `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` and you can just test for the existence of the "test" setting, assuming production if its not there, then in the constructor create a real identifier or prefixed with "X_" for test.

Comment: @Ron I probably owe you an apology. I clarified my needs in my question now--I shouldn't have presented a global test/prod flag scenario. It does need to be recipient-sensitive.

Comment: As you're using the MessageBuilder with property initialization, why not add a constructor to it which handles that logic. Require your Devs to use that constructor which has the messageDetails object as parameter. You have your DRY principle covered there. Additionally, you can provide an DI injected class which supply the knowledge about test mode for recipients.

Comment: @NielsV This gives me an idea. I had toyed with the idea of (and plalx suggested) having a `ProductionIdentifier` and a `TestIdentifier`, both subclassing the abstract `Identifier` class. The `MessageBuilder` could then accept the correct type such as `new MessageBuilder { ... }.Build<Message1234, TestIdentifier>()` which would constrain all Identifiers to be converted to that type upon building/usage. Or, just pass in a boolean and work on the identifiers manually. So the message generator knows *how* to make test identifiers, but the business layer says *when to*.

Comment: @ErikE Did my answer make any sense?

Comment: @plalx It helps some, but things are still really unclear. I haven't had a chance to try to implement anything so am not sure what is going to work out in practice.

Answer (score 1):

What about using an identifier factory?

```
IdentifierFactory                   <-- ProductionIdentifierFactory
+CreateFrom(String identifier)      <-- TestIdentifierFactory
```

In your composition root, you would instantiate the right `IdentifierFactory` implementation based on the environment.

Then you could just do the following everywhere:

```
Identifier identifier = identifierFactory.CreateFrom(somesString);
```

If you want you can also factor out what it means to be a production or a test identifier from the factory itself by having multiple concrete identifier classes: `ProductionIdentifier` and `TestIdentifier`

EDIT:

At the time of writing I did not realize that the environment was actually determined by the recipients identifier.

In that case perhaps you could make the `MessageDetails` class a factory for those identifiers. Base on it's recipient's identifier code, the message detail would return test or production identifiers.

```
public void SendMessage(MessageDetails messageDetails) {
    Identifier recipient = messageDetails.Recipient;
    Identifier sender = messageDetails.Sender;

    //...
}
```

This would somewhat be a bit more inline with the [Tell Don't Ask principle](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html). What would be even better is to ask `MessageDetails` to build your message.

If you do not want to pollute any of your business classes with those concerns then you may want to rely on AOP. You could still make the `MessageDetails` a factory for the identifiers, but use AOP to change the behavior of those factory methods.

Finally, if you will have `new Identifier(...)` all over the place, not only when sending messages, etc then it becomes much more complex. Sure you could always pass in an `Environment` variable everywhere but that's a lot of noise.

**I do not know C# very well so there might be more idiomatic mechanisms**, but you may try to run operations on individual threads and then rely on ThreadLocal variables to create isolated scopes. At this point I guess we would need to know more about your domain to provide an efficient solution.

Comment: I know what AOP is but would love to hear a concrete example of how to achieve what you're suggesting in C#.

Comment: Well, you would basically use an "after advice" for the `Recipient` and `Sender` getters of the `MessageDetails` class that would change the return value based on wheter the `recipient` is a testing identifier or not. Therefore, there wouldn't be any of that code in `MessageDetails` directly.

Comment: Your advice to use AOP was helpful. I ended up not actually using AOP, but it focused my thoughts on where, if I were to use it, I would hook in my PointCuts. This led me to realize that the issue of production vs. test is only a *serialization time* concern. Therefore, I added a parameter to the serialization method that indicates if it is test or production, and then as the serialization code traverses the data structure, if it finds an `Identifier`, it converts it to test or not. Thank you for your help.